# JQuery new Date() and loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I'm trying to make simple weather app and I'm having some problems.
I'm using API from openweathermap.org to get min and max temp.
This is mine key:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?callback=fetchData&q=London&appid=redacted&units=metric&_=1481140918291
```

Now for the API I'm using they don't provide the date so I tried to do it on my own with this code:

```
forecast.list.forEach(function(forecastEntry, index, list){

    today = new Date();

    html += '<p>'+ today + ': ' + forecastEntry.temp.min + '< ' + forecastEntry.temp.max + '</p>'

})
```

Now this gets my some output like this:

Wed Dec 07 2016 22:29:27 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time): 9.62< 12.58

Wed Dec 07 2016 22:29:27 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time): -6.73< 5.66

Wed Dec 07 2016 22:29:27 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time): -7.95< 9.17

Wed Dec 07 2016 22:29:27 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time): -6.34< 11.77

Wed Dec 07 2016 22:29:27 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time): -2< 14.5

Wed Dec 07 2016 22:29:27 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time): 1.72< 13.46

I have tried doing something like this:

```
for (i=0;i<8;i++) {
        var today = new Date();
        today.setDate(today.getDate()+i);
        console.log(today);
        html += '<p>' + today + forecastEntry.temp.min + '< ' + forecastEntry.temp.max + '</p>'
}
```

This solves the days problem but it repeats my whole output many times I presume because of my forEach loop. I'm new to JS and I'm really having trouble solving this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Here is JSBIN of my whole code: http://jsbin.com/lafurih/edit?html,js,output

EDIT: To clarify my problem. Output shows 8 days I want but it shows them 8 times.

Comment: You've described what it does but not what you want it to do.  Can you please specify the expected behavior?

Comment: You should be careful in publishing your appid, as now anyone can use it and they'll be able to use up your allotment of requests...

Comment: @JohnWu Look at JSBIN and type London for example now you will see output many times, but I just wan't it 1 time.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yeah I know it's risky but I wanted to describe my problem in detail ....

Comment: ??  You want it one time ??? Thought you wanted eight days of forecasts.  If you want just one day, get rid of the for loop.  Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @JohnWu I want 8 days. But this 8 days repeat 8 times. Have you checked my JSBin !!

Comment: As @Mike McCaughan mentions, the public API key is a bad idea, I'd get it revoked once you find an answer if I were you.

Comment: @KristofferlaCour Yeah I guess I should do it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you put the for loop within the foreach loop. This should work: http://jsbin.com/hiyupisivi/edit?html,js,output

I removed the for loop, and put the I variable outside the foreach loop, then increment it every time the loop runs.

In the end the function will look like this:

```
function fetchData (forecast) {
    console.log(forecast)
    var html = '',
    cityName = forecast.city.name,
    country = forecast.city.country,
    cnt = forecast.cnt
    var i = 0;

    html += '<h3> Weather Forecast for ' + cityName + ', ' + country + ', ' + cnt + ' days</h3>'
    forecast.list.forEach(function(forecastEntry, index, list){
            var today = new Date();
            today.setDate(today.getDate()+i);
            console.log(today);
            html += '<p>' + today + forecastEntry.temp.min + '< ' + forecastEntry.temp.max + '</p>'
            i++;
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you running the exact same code? It worked for me.

Comment: It works there was a problem with JSBin that's why it didn't work for me at first. THANK you very much.

Comment: Please include the code you changed in the question itself. This answer will be less helpful for others if that site goes down or that example is deleted from their site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Do you mean me ? In that case do I need to add solution in my question ?

Comment: Sorry, that's a boilerplate comment. Include the code in the answer.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan So I should answer my own question ?  I'm sorry for stupid questions i'm not sure what do you want me to do.

Comment: No, I want @KristofferlaCour to copy the relevant portion of their code to their answer. I didn't mention you, it was a comment to the answer.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yeah that's what I thought

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan There you go.